# Rails database chicken and egg error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm refactoring a Rails app. In one table I have a column named `set` that I need to rename to `configuration_set`. I have changed the code cope with the change and created a migration to rename the column.

The problem now is that I can't run the migration:

```
class AlignConfigurationValuesColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration

def self.up
  rename_column :configuration_values, :set, :configuration_set
end
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `find_by_configuration_set_and_key' for #<Class:0x7f2c7a879580>
```

The undefined function is a dynamic find_by method that is called on the new code but it doesn't exist until the database migration is executed.

Any ideas?
Thx

Comment: can you post the migration code?

Comment: change the code back, migrate, and then fix the code?

Comment: @JamesAdam - Rails crashes before the migration is executed. I've added it to the problem description.

Comment: @MikeCampbell I could do that but how am I going to deploy it then? Shall I do 2 releases? One to execute the migration and one with the new code?

Comment: I don't know how you deploy, but with capistrano I'd run `cap deploy:migrate`, then `cap deploy`.

Comment: @MikeCampbell The server is in a closed network and application code is essentially released as a tarball. After uncompressing, rake db:migrate is executed and the application restarted. At the moment I have the app working but I had to migrate the DB by using the MySQL client command line.

Comment: it sounds like rake db:migrate is not being run before the application is restarted... wild guess: Do you need to include the correct RAILS_ENV=blah parameter in your rake db:migrate call?

Comment: It does indeed sound like the migration isn't being run.  On Heroku, it'd get run before the server is restarted.  Whatever your deployment environment, you'll need to make sure that the migration gets run first.  Is one of your other, earlier migrations using model code or doing something dynamic?  If so, it's best to avoid using any code from your app from within a migration, specifically because of this problem.

Comment: @JimStewart I'm not using any app code within the migrations. I guess running the migration before restarting the server may work for a production environment, but not sure if it would work in a development environment where classes are reloaded when they are edited.

Comment: You should always shut your server down before you run migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the migration crashes because the dynamic method `find_by_configuration_set_and_key` is undefined. This dynamic method will only be defined after the migration is executed as the migration is renaming column `set` to `configuration_set`.

I have now found a way to execute the migration although it's not perfect.

The code where method `find_by_configuration_set_and_key` is called lays within a plugin. I changed environment.rb so that the plugin is not loaded and that allowed me to run the Rails database migration. Then I put it back and restarted the app.

This solution is better then using the mysql client but still a hack.
Thanks to everyone for the nice ideas and discussion.

Comment: Definign the model within the migration also seemed interesting but I couldn't get it to work: http://bit.ly/15uOiPE

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `change_column`, try:

```
rename_column :configuration_values, :set, :configuration_set
```

Comment: You're right about the migration syntax and I've updated the problem description. However the migration is not the problem. Rails crashes before the migration is executed because the dynamic method find_by_configuration_set_and_key does not exist as column configuration_set does not exist. It will only exist after the migration is executed.